# logistic Regression on a arrays of various sizes

Tags: python, numpy, regression, logistic-regression

In an audio classification exercise, I am trying to do a logistic regression where my X_train is a list. In fact, the list contains 100 elements and each element is an array of size: N*1
But after doing the fit, I have the error of "**setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (100,) + inhomogeneous part**."
which I imagine is because of various size of the elements of my list.
My question is: how can I equalize the size of the elements? For example, making my list a list of arrays of size 500*1 ?

```
mfcc_all = []
labels_all = []

for i in range (100):
    entry = entries.loc[i,:]
    mfcc = load_mfcc(entry, _msdi_path)
    mfcc_all.append(mfcc)
    y = get_label(entry)
    labels_all.append(y)

logReg = LogisticRegression()
logReg.fit(mfcc_all, labels_all)
```

Comment: would you say that your data could be represented by a matrix `X` with dimensions `n x d`? because I think that this is what the regression needs (as in `n` samples and `d` features)

Comment: You're right. I need a matrix of n * d size. But I don't know how to convert this list containing arrays with various size into a matrix of n * d ! :(

Comment: you've specified `N` and `N1`, how are those not constant?

Comment: Sorry maybe I need to reformulate my question. My X_train for the regression is an ensemble of lists from different sizes. How can I equalize the size of each list. For example length of the first list is 198 and length of the second list 1 is 1978 ! What can I do ?